# operator = problem. Why is this happening?

Tags: c++, oop

So i have written the following method in a class:

```
Array & operator = (const Array &a) {
  /*delete [] array;
    priv_size = a.priv_size;                        HOW DOES THIS EVEN DO SOMETHING???
    priv_base = a.priv_base;
    array = new int[priv_size*priv_size];

    for (int i=0; i<priv_size*priv_size; i++)
        array[i] = a.array[i];

    return *this;
*/
}
```

as you can clearly see it is all in one big comment. However, when i call the `=` operator in `main` like this:

```
  cout << a; //there is an operator << too
  cout << endl;
  Array b = a;
  b[1][1] = 39;
  b[3][1] = 2;
  cout << b;
  cout << endl;
  cout << a;
```

where a is the following array:

```
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   3   0   0   0
   0   0   0   5
```

this happens:

```
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   3   0   0   0
   0   0   0   5

   0   0   0   0
   0  39   0   0
   3   0   0   0
   0   2   0   5

   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   3   0   0   0
   0   0   0   5
```

As you can see i also change some values in `b`, but `a` remains intact which means `b` is not by mistake somehow connected to `a` in any way.

What is going on here? Help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I moved the comment so that it covers the whole method **including the `Array & operator = (const Array &a)` part**. The exact same thing happens(????). How is this possible? It almost seems like there is already a default `operator =` method, which does't really make too much sense, because why would c++ prioritize such a method, and even if it does, why set it so that it copies a whole array?.

Also, here is the constructor, since a lot of people needed to see it:

```
Array (int s = 0, int b = 0) :
    array(new int[s*s]), priv_size(s), priv_base(b) {
    for (int i=0; i<priv_size*priv_size; i++)
        array[i] = 0;                                //sets everything to 0
}
```

Comment: `Array b = a;` is not assignment - it's copy initialisation - we need to see the constructor.  Please post a [mcve].  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization  case (1).

Comment: ***you can clearly see it is all in one big comment.*** Would create undefined behavior if operator=() was used. however its not.

Comment: If you uncomment the code, you should also check for self assignment. `a = a;` would also lead to UB since you `delete[] array;` and create a new uninitialized array that you read from (and you'd loose the data too).

Comment: Rather than `array = new int[priv_size*priv_size];` where `int* array;` is a member variable, switch to `std::vector` and do `array = a.array;` where `std::vector<int> array;` is the member variable.  It'll fix several bugs in the program.

Comment: @RichardCritten the question is edited, hope this is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: As I said in my 1st comment this is not assignment. So the assignment operator is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is answered:

In my example i wrote `Array b = a;`, which in c++ calls the `copy constructor` and not the `opperator =`

This is documented here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

As well as here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read the question and comment.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo thanks for pointing this out!